# spring-data postgres transaction isolation issue

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I have two entities: `Message` and `Session`.
`Message` has a `@ManyToOne` relationship to `Session`.

I have a Spring Data repository and action A:

```
@Query("select c from Messages c where c.session.mode=0 and c.field=5")
List<Messages> findMessages();
```

Then I process found data

```
messages.ForEach(message->{
    Session session = message.getSession();
    sessionClose(session);
    newSessionOpen();
})
```

and in other service class I have

```
Session session=findOpenedSession();
```

The question is:

What if action A in transaction and after it starts and before it ends other service will request opened `Session` or will try to insert a record to `Message` table?

In other words we have:

1. Transaction starts
2. Records are being read
3. `Session` instances get processed in a loop - `Session` using `sessionClose` and `newSessionOpen`
4. Transaction ends

What if some other process will request opened `Session` between 2 and 4 or 2 and 3 or somewhere within?
So which opened `Session` will it read? Old one or new one? 
I use postgres and `@Transactional` Spring annotation.

Comment: You completly confused me. When you say session, do you mean a jpa entity you created or a hibernate session? Or maybe sometimes one and sometimes the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming 'session' in your question always refers to the entity you created.

According to this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html the default isolation level of postgres prevents dirty reads. So no other transaction will be able to see any changes made in your first transaction, until that transaction commits (i.e. ends).

According to the same source you can set the transaction isolation level to read uncommited. In such a scenario a second transaction might be able to see changes done by the first transaction, although the first transaction is not yet commited. Note though that changes to entities are not imediately written to the database, but only flushed before end of the transaction, explicite call to flush or if configured, before selects get executed. So although your database settings might allow dirty reads you might not experience them due to the behavior of JPA/Hibernate